# How can we know the capital appreciation of property in an area?

Tags: investing, real-estate, capital-gain, long-term

Let's say I wanted to buy a property in a certain area, I want to know how much of appreciation I am expecting in the next 5 years. What are methods that one can determine the appreciation?

Comment: Many methods exists - however finding out which one is the right one is impossible. No one knows what the market looks like in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how much of appreciation I am expecting in the next 5 years.

It is utterly impossible to know this.

It is sheer luck.

If you mean in *previous* years ...

> How can we know the capital appreciation of property in an area?

These days it is incredibly easy to find this information.  For example in the USA, zillow.com or a dozen competitors.

Use a search engine to instantly find vast amounts of such house price data.